# How to retrieve all model data from a view in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to build a widget designing system where a user can submit the title and html of the widget.Now when I try query the Widget model in a view and pass the data to `@foreach` loop,I get the error as `@foreach` is not able to iterate over the queryset returned by `Widget::all()`.How can I display all the data from Widget model on my webpage?

Btw my Widget model has only two fields(i.e title and html).

EDIT:Following is the `var_dump` of what I get in return when I do `Widget::all()`

```
array(2) { [0]=> object(Widget)#42 (5) { ["attributes"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["title"]=> string(24) "Join Demo classes today!" ["html"]=> string(47) "
This is just the great demo of widgets.
" } ["original"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["title"]=> string(24) "Join Demo classes today!" ["html"]=> string(47) "
This is just the great demo of widgets.
" } ["relationships"]=> array(0) { } ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["includes"]=> array(0) { } } [1]=> object(Widget)#45 (5) { ["attributes"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["title"]=> string(12) "About Google" ["html"]=> string(66) "Google is the best site in the world." } ["original"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["title"]=> string(12) "About Google" ["html"]=> string(66) "Google is the best site in the world." } ["relationships"]=> array(0) { } ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["includes"]=> array(0) { } } }
```

Comment: How are you looping it looks like an object array. Must be a loop issue.

Comment: Perhaps you can show your action code and your view code.  There's no reason you shouldn't be able to iterate over the results of `Widget::all()`

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to solve your problem without any code. Here's what I would do:

controller:

```
$widgets = Widget::all();
View::make('html.widgets')->with('widgets', $widgets);
```

view (blade):

```
@foreach($widgets as $widget)
    {{ $widget->title }}
    {{ $widget->html }}
@endforeach
```

In the question you're mentioning query the widget in a view. As this is clearly against MVC principles but demonstrates the flexibility of laravel, I will also give you a snippet how one can do that without a controller. I do **not** recommend this:

```
@foreach(Widget::all() as $widget)
    {{ $widget->title }}
    {{ $widget->html }}
@endforeach
```